# How to connect Lightsail with Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache, amazon-lightsail

How do we connect AWS Lightsail to Elasticache? I've set VPC peering but that's as far as I get. Anyone knows a step-by-step guide that shows how to do it?

[edit]

We have an application that uses Memcached to persist some data between nodes. The installation currently uses 4 servers: two nodes, 1 RDBMS and 1 Memcached server and is currently running on DigitalOcean servers. Our intention is to install the nodes on Lightsail servers and use AWS services directly from the Lightsail servers, such as RDS and Elasticache.

There are no problems connecting to an RDS MySQL instance from the Lightsail servers but a timeout occurs when trying to attach to the Memcached service. I know it's a security issue, I just can't find any doc that makes that connection work.

Comment: Could you please expand upon your configuration? For example, have you launched an Elasticache cluster already? What do you mean by "connect Lightsail to Elasticache" -- presumably you have an application installed on the Lightsail instance? Feel free to Edit your question to add further details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hey John do you think you could direct me to some info on how to be able to establish a connection to elasticache from Lightsail? At this point we're using DigitalOcean and we're running all the servers. I'd like to transfer the secondary stuff to services like RDS, Elasticache and others. Thx.

Comment: I don't have any specific advice about connecting AWS Lightsail to Amazon ElastiCache, but the first step would be to check the Security Group associated with ElastiCache. Start by testing it as open to the world (`0.0.0.0/0`) to see whether that fixes communications, then lock it down to the desired range. It might also be related to how the ElastiCache DNS name resolves to a public/private IP address.

Comment: Elasticache unfortunately only allow internal traffic, meaning that you can't connect with a public IP. Even though you have set up VPC Peering, but if your Elasitcache doesn't reside inside the Default VPC (which Lightsails peers with) you still won't be able to connect. Also, transitive peering is not supported, so you can't peer from your Lightsail to the Default VPC to the VPC where your Elasticache resides.